# Maxing out server memory with basic php script

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been battling this for quite some time, I am running a simple php script on my server, which pulls 15 days max worth of data from 6 tables, each having at most 5 columns of no more that 20 chars each column. But for some reason each time the script is run the server is reporting it to use 560 megs of ram. My host has denied any responsibility, so I am giving the benefit of the doubt and chasing my tail to try and my fault. Any suggestions or reassurances on this script would be greatly appreciated..

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
require_once('xxx');

$date = "";

if ($data === null) {
    echo 'Invalid Access';
} else {
    foreach ($data as $date) {
    } 
    $tables = array('Seizures', 'medlist', 'Output', 'Feeds', 'HydKeto', 'MedLogs');
    global $dbc;
    $rows = array();

    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        if ($table != 'medlist') {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE timestamp > '$date'";
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE status!='dc'";
        }
        $sth = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if ($sth != null) {
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
                $rows[$table][] = $r;
            }
        }
    mysqli_free_result($sth);
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Comment: How much data is in $rows after this script? PS: you could do that in one query using `UNION`

Comment: I see sql injection possibilities. Can you?

Comment: What are you taking from `php://input`?

Comment: As for the sql injection, I will be doing data sanitization and security once I work out the memory issue, if it is my memory issue. the php://input is receiving a timestamp date from a phone.

Comment: zerkms I made a test script in the past that downloaded the max amount of data this script should ever get from the sql database and it was around 500k I believe. This is why I am stumped. There is no doubling of data, what is returned is exactly what is asked for. At the moment it is definitely messy code, but I really don't see why it should be using over 500 megs. each time its run.

Comment: mysqli_query is **NEVER** going to return null. It'll either be a result set, or a boolean true/false. Your $date value is also never set, so your time comparison is always going to be `timestamp > ''`, e.g. select **ALL** records, unless that empty foreach loop leaves $date set to some valid timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a cloudLinux issue, not logging memory accurately. My Host finally admitted to it and fixed it after banging my head against the wall for 3 months.